# spring-boot:run for multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have a micro services setup of Eureka Server and multiple spring-boot applications as Eureka Clients. This is setup as maven multi module project at the parent (root) level. Below is the hierarchy:

```
parent (multi-module parent pom.xml)
  |_ eureka-server-spring-boot-app (individual pom.xml)
  |_ eureka-client-spring-boot-app-1 (individual pom.xml)
  |_ eureka-client-spring-boot-app-2 (individual pom.xml)
  |_ eureka-client-spring-boot-app-3 (individual pom.xml)
  .
  .
```

I was trying to run all the modules in the order defined in parent pom.xml. But when I run `mvn spring-boot:run` at parent level it only runs the first module (Eureka Server). Other modules are not deployed. I tried reading through SO but no relevant answers found.

I want maven to run all the modules in order from parent directory. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: @Karthikeyan The problem in this case has nothing to do with [tag:microservices] nor with [tag:netflix-eureka].

Comment: I agree. I just gave the additional information. So if the project structure is wrong then I can correct that as well. Any suggestions @g00glen00b?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because Maven will sequentially run those Maven plugins on each project, however, since running a Spring boot project doesn't terminate immediately, it will never reach the `spring-boot:run` goal for the second or third module. A solution would be to create a separate shell script and make each of the modules run in a different thread. I don't know if there's a thing like that for Maven. Forking the JVM didn't seem to do the trick at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mvn spring-boot:start` instead as this won't block other operations

Comment: It does not really start the application. I believe it is meant to start the application before running the integration tests and stops after that. So even if this starts, it could be a good hack/workaround but not really for production right?

Comment: **EDIT** With `mvn spring-boot:run` it deploys/runs the application but stops after running eureka-server module which is first one in order. To use `mvn spring-boot:start` do I have to make any changes in parent pom.xml? It fails with the error as `No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project`.

Comment: The idea would be that you add the plugin config to each sub-module, bind to a goal somewhere in between clean and install, and then just run `mvn clean install` from the root module

Comment: I agree it's not good for production, but probably no config using the maven plugin will be suitable for production. As @g00glen00b suggests, a scripted solution or Jenkins job-based solution using Puppet/Chef is probably better.